# How to create a styled table using OpenPyXl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I need to create a table with openpyxl. Can anyone help me create a styled table with openpyxl?

[image: table image]

This is my function example:

Script using openpyxl demonstrates how to create a styled Excel table with custom borders, merged cells, and cell coloring. The script initializes a workbook, adds a worksheet, and applies various styles such as PatternFill for cell backgrounds, and Border styles for cell borders, including thin, thick, double, and medium borders.

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Border, Side, Alignment, Font, fills

THIN_BORDER = Border(left=Side(border_style='thin',color='FF000000'),
                    right=Side(border_style='thin',color='FF000000'),
                    top=Side(border_style='thin',color='FF000000'),
                    bottom=Side(border_style='thin',color='FF000000')
                    )
                    
THICK_BORDER = Border(left=Side(border_style='thin',color='FF000000'),
                    right=Side(border_style='thin',color='FF000000'),
                    top=Side(border_style='thin',color='FF000000'),
                    bottom=Side(border_style='medium',color='FF000000')
                    )
DOUBLE_BORDER = Border(left=Side(border_style='dashed',color='FF000000'),
                    right=Side(border_style='dashed',color='FF000000'),
                    top=Side(border_style='double',color='FF000000'),
                    bottom=Side(border_style='double',color='FF000000')
                    )
MEDIUM_BORDER = Border(left=Side(border_style='medium',color='FF000000'),
                    right=Side(border_style='medium',color='FF000000'),
                    top=Side(border_style='medium',color='FF000000'),
                    bottom=Side(border_style='medium',color='FF000000')
                    ) 

def create_styled_table():
        
    wb=Workbook()
    ws1=wb.active
    ws1.title = "Sheet1"
    ws1.sheet_properties.tabColor = '000000FF'
    
    #Define fill formating 
    fill_cell = PatternFill(fill_type=fills.FILL_SOLID,start_color='00FFFF00',end_color='00FFFF00')
    #define size of the table 
    row_num=9
    col_num=8 
    #location of the Table 
    start_row, row_loc = 10, 10
    start_column, col_loc = 2, 2
    #Number of Tables 
    Table_num=1
    dis=2 # distance between the tables 
    for _ in range(Table_num):
        for i in range (row_loc,row_loc+row_num):
            for j in range (col_loc,col_num+col_loc):
                ws1.cell(row=i, column=j).border=THIN_BORDER
                if i==row_loc:
                    ws1.cell(row=i, column=j).border=DOUBLE_BORDER
                    ws1.cell(row=i, column=j).fill=fill_cell
                if i==row_loc+row_num-1:
                    ws1.cell(row=i, column=j).border=THICK_BORDER
        row_loc= row_loc+row_num+dis
        
    ws1.merge_cells(start_row=start_row, start_column=start_column+2, end_row=start_row, end_column=start_column+col_num-1)
    ws1.cell(row=start_row, column=start_column+col_num-1).border=MEDIUM_BORDER
    
    ws1.merge_cells(start_row=start_row, start_column=start_column, end_row=start_row+1, end_column=start_column)
    ws1.merge_cells(start_row=start_row+2, start_column=start_column, end_row=start_row+row_num-1, end_column=start_column)
            
    wb.save('table.xlsx')`
```

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for worksheet tables?